# Why discuss the 10 martyrs on Yom Kippur?

Tags: yom-kippur

In the yom kippur musaf my community recited a poem going through the whole story of the deaths of the "asara harugai malchus" the ten martyrs. It is a "חטאנו" poem recited before the confession section.

Why on yom kippur do we mourn their deaths, seemingly it has no specific connection to yom kippur? We should mourn their deaths on tisha b'av?

Comment: We do mourn them on Tisha Bav. There's a Kina about it.

Comment: In my machazor, there's a completely different chatanu (Rödelheim edition, printed by Goldschmidt Basel)

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Is there any Piyut that is universal in all traditions? Why is it important to note yours is different?

Comment: @DoubleAA, oh, we say אלה אזכרה alright, it's just on 'erev R"H, rather than on Y"K. I figure that this lends another perspective with which to view Ashkenazi liturgy, due to the near-universality of the Polish seder piyutim in contemporary Ashkenazi machazorim

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Why not rephrase and repost your comment to say the important point (some say it on a different occasion) instead of the not relevant point (some don't say it when 'you' do)

Answer (score 2):

Rashi Bemidbar 20:1

> Why was the death of Miriam juxtaposed to the parah adumah? To teach us that just like sacrifices atone, so too does the death of the righteous.

I assume (and, if I remember correctly, Rav Soloveitchik says this in his machzor) that the deaths are being invoked as some kind of kapparah.

Comment: the Artscroll Machzor, page 586, reads, "in order to evoke feelings of loss ans repentance on the part of the congregation"

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't have the time right now to delve into [this](http://www.hakirah.org/Vol13Levine.pdf) long article right now, it seem to spend over 20 pages addressing your question. One line that sticks out to me is:

> Arzei  ha-Levanon  by  clear  allusion  identifies  the  Martyrs  as 
>   Yom  Kippur  sacrifices:  ",לב טהור יש חי קדשי םקדשי טתן חמורה במיתה" “Pure of
>   heart, holiest of holy ones, Kodshei Kodashim, their slaughtering  in
>   a  severe  death,”  paraphrasing  Mishnah  Zevahim  5:1: 
>   איזהו של מקומן שחיטתן קדשי םקדשי זבחי םשחיטתן הכפורים יום של ושעיר פר בצפון בצפון,
>   “Kodshei  Kodashim,  their  slaughtering  is  in  the  north,  the  ox
>   and goat of Yom Kippur, their slaughtering is in the north.